review dyamic apps script to fetch value from weblink table and sum into sheet based on criteria
Trying to have the below app script in google sheet run. goal is script to be dynamic. it should pick up stock symbol starting cell d6 go to weblink find "p - purchase" buys in last 6 months and sum the value into cell m6 and then do this for any stocks below automatically from sheet called "dash".
function fetchAndSumPurchasesForMultipleStocks() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getsheetbyname("dash");

  // Specify the range where the stock symbols are located (e.g., column A)
  var stockSymbolRange = sheet.getRange("d6:d");  // Adjust as needed
  var stockSymbols = stockSymbolRange.getValues().flat().filter(String);  // Get and filter non-empty stock symbols

  // Loop through each stock symbol
  for (var i = 0; i < stockSymbols.length; i++) {
    var stockSymbol = stockSymbols[i].trim();

    if (!stockSymbol) continue;  // Skip if the stock symbol is empty

    // Fetch and sum the purchases for this stock symbol
    var sum = fetchAndSumPurchases(stockSymbol);
    
    // Output the result in the corresponding cell in column M
    var outputCell = sheet.getRange(i + 6, 13);  // Column M is the 13th column
    outputCell.setValue(sum);
  }
}

function fetchAndSumPurchases(stockSymbol) {
  var url = "http://openinsider.com/screener?s=" + encodeURIComponent(stockSymbol) + "&o=&pl=&ph=&ll=&lh=&fd=180&fdr=&td=0&tdr=&fdlyl=&fdlyh=&daysago=&xp=1&xs=1&vl=&vh=&ocl=&och=&sic1=-1&sicl=&sich=&grp=0&nfl=&nfh=&nil=&nih=&nol=&noh=&v2l=&v2h=&oc2l=&oc2h=&sortcol=0&cnt=100&page=1";
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var html = response.getContentText();
  
  var doc = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).getContent();
  var startIndex = doc.indexOf('<table class="tinytable">');
  var endIndex = doc.indexOf('</table>', startIndex);
  var tableHTML = doc.slice(startIndex, endIndex + 8);

  var sum = 0;

  // Split the table into rows
  var rows = tableHTML.split('<tr>');

  // Loop through each row to find the stock and add up purchases
  for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) { // Start from 1 to skip headers
    var cells = rows[i].split('<td>');
    
    // Assuming the trade type and stock symbol are in specific columns (adjust indices as needed)
    var tradeType = cells[6].replace(/<[^>]*>?/gm, '').trim(); // Assuming column 7 (4th index)
    var symbol = cells[3].replace(/<[^>]*>?/gm, '').trim(); // Assuming column 4 (3nd index)
    var value = parseFloat(cells[11].replace(+/<[^>]*>?/gm, '').replace(/,/g, '').trim()); // Assuming column 12 (11th index)

    if (tradeType === "P - Purchase" && symbol === stockSymbol) {
      sum += value;
    }
  }

  return sum;
}

2 problems:

TypeError: SpreadsheetApp.getsheetbyname is not a function
the return is 0 or table is blank but i know its not. for example stock atec has inside purchases last 6 months.

Ive tried justing using active sheet which fixed 1 but i need it to be specific sheet. Ive tried playing around with column references and tried using gemini but didnt help.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Ask only one question per post. See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.


TypeError: SpreadsheetApp.getsheetbyname is not a function

There is no SpreadsheetApp.getsheetbyname() method.
Use SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName() instead.
See Spreadsheet.getSheetByName().
